# How to SELECT from two table as one table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables (sql server)

```
SELECT x, id, y, z
FROM table1

SELECT a, id, b, c
FROM table2
```

I want the results to be merged (not a union)

Where the id value is a match in both tables then the result would be

```
x, id, y, z, a, id, b, c
```

where the id is only in table 1 then the result would be

```
x, id, y, z, null, id, null, null
```

where the id is only in table 2 then the result would be

```
null, id, null, null, a, id, b, c
```

the id appearing once or twice makes no difference

I have spent many hours on this to no avail

Is this possible?

Comment: [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: Check the 'Using Full Outer Joins' part on the linked page. The is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) keyword;

```
SELECT t1.x,  t1.id,  t1.y,  t1.z, t2.a, t2.id, t2.b, t2.c
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
On t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    table1.x, ISNULL(table1.id,table2.id) [id], table1.y, table1.z
   ,table2.a, ISNULL(table1.id,table2.id) [id], table2.b, table2.c
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
```